# Reversing the Items In a Collection

Tags: vba, collections

What is the easiest way to reverse the items in a VBA collection?

Comment: you could take a look at [vbaforall: Reverse order in a For Each loop](https://web.archive.org/web/20141014162937/http://vba4all.com/reverse-order-of-in-a-for-each-loop/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't know of any neat way of doing it but you could do something like (code not tested):

```
Dim MyNewCol as New Collection
For Each obj in MyCol
    If MyNewCol.Count > 0 Then
        MyNewCol.Add item := obj, before := 1
    Else
        MyNewCol.Add item := obj
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps down through the starting collection beginning from the member with the largest index. Adds each member to the reversed collection.

```
Sub ReverseCollection(aCollection)

    Dim ndx As Integer
    Dim max As Integer
    Dim reversedCollection As New Collection
    max = aCollection.Count + 1

    For ndx = 1 To aCollection.Count
        reversedCollection.Add aCollection(max - ndx)
    Next ndx
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Uses the built-in iterator over the starting collection.
To use 'Add, Before', the collection must have at least 1 member, so add an item and then remove it after the reversed collection is finished.

```
Sub ReverseCollection2(aCollection)

   Dim item As Variant
   Dim reversedCollection As New Collection
   reversedCollection.Add "dummy entry"
   For Each item In aCollection
       reversedCollection.Add item, Before:=1
   Next item
   reversedCollection.Remove reversedCollection.Count
End Sub
```