# How to insert a single blank row ABOVE and not below specific repeated row

Tags: vba, excel

I using the below macro and it inserts the row below the cell with "Card Number"

I cannot get it to go above the row no matter what I do. Probably quite basic for some but have recently only found how useful macros are

```
Sub Insert()
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("A1:A5000")
If c.Value Like "*Card Number:*" Then
c.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
End If
Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Offseting it moves the selection one row down; try `c.EntireRow.Insert`

Comment: Thanks,  tried that - but it went into tail spin when I ran it and shut down excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably tried you cannot just do `c.EntireRow.Insert` since it will insert a line above and it will keep in the `For Each` loop infinitely. The solution is to loop through the range in reverse, like done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26911575/1771479):

```
Sub InsertRev()
    Dim c As Range
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A5000")
    For dblCounter = rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = rng(dblCounter)
        If c.Value Like "*Card Number:*" Then
           c.EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next dblCounter
End Sub
```

Comment: A Plus for AGold - Your a genius !  thank so so much

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve this problem but I'm not that advanced in macros and I'm sure there is a better way.

```
Sub Insert()
For i = 1 To 5000
   If Cells(i, "A") Like "*Card Number:*" Then ' loop trough 5000 cells in column A
       Rows(i + 1).Insert 'insert bottom row first so it doesn't mess with row numbers
       Rows(i - 1).Insert 'then you can insert upper row
       i = i + 1 'jump over the next row as it now contains the card number for sure
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It would be easier to use `Step -1` to go from bottom to top, to avoid adding multiples rows! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `Offset` in that case, the `Insert` command always insert rows above the selection.

Further more, if you use `for each`, you don't have control on the direction in which your loop will be, so it is better to use `for i =` with `step -1` to go from bottom to top.

**Why?** Because if you insert a new row from row i, the row i will become the row i+1 and you will test it on the next loop and keep adding rows!

```
Sub Insert_Rows()
Dim i As Long

For i = 5000 To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(i, "A").Value Like "*Card Number:*" Then
        Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Insert
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```