# Excel VBA: Delete rows if value not equal to a value?

Tags: excel, vba

So I've been searching hard to find why my code hasn't been working, but every time I try, I get a result where nothing is changed.  Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?  Sorry, I'm a total novice but I'm trying.

```
   Dim Cell As Range

With Sheets(1)
    ' loop column D until last cell with value (not entire column)
    For Each Cell In .Range("D2:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
        If Cell.Value <> 110 Then
            Rows(Cell.Row).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next Cell
End With
```

Comment: Try adding a `.` to `Rows(Cell.Row).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: 2 things. If you're deleting rows, you need to go backwards through the collection. Also, you need to fully qualify `Rows(Cell.Row).EntireRow.Delete`.

Comment: I'm very sorry, but can you explain what qualify means?

Comment: `Cell.EntireRow.Delete` would be more direct

Comment: [this might be of use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358183/reverse-order-of-for-each-loop)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439376/what-is-the-default-scope-of-worksheets-and-cells-and-range/28439984#28439984

Comment: I'm reading through the posts and working on figuring it out, but thank you all so much for your help!  This goes a long way!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of looping, make use of excels inbuilt functions, its cleaner and more concise.

```
With Sheets(1).UsedRange
    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>110"
    .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    .AutoFilter
End With
```

if you insist on looping then use the following code:

```
With Sheets(1).UsedRange
    For lrow = .Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If .Cells(lrow, 4).Value <> 110 Then .Rows(lrow).Delete
    Next lrow
End With
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  Yes, I'll research more into the inbuilt functions to get better, but both of these codes worked perfectly, thank you.

Comment: @ElAsado, just a heads up. You might need to change `"=110"` to `"<>110"` here, as your title and original post suggests you want to delete the rows where column D does not equal 110. But other than that, you're good I think.

Comment: @Reafidy: You probably haven't noticed, the first solution deletes row 1 regardless of the content. Know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but maybe something like:

```
Option explicit

Sub DeleteRows()

With thisworkbook.worksheets(1)
    ' loop column D until last cell with value (not entire column)

Dim lastRow as long
lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

Dim rowIndex as long
For rowIndex = lastRow to 2 step -1

If .cells(rowIndex, "D").value2 <> 110 then
.cells(rowIndex, "D").entirerow.delete
End if

Next rowIndex

End With

End sub
```

If you have a lot of rows, you could use `union` to build a range consisting of all rows to be deleted, then delete them in one go.