# Best code to delete all rows containing a specific word in column O?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete all the rows containing the word "Resigned" only in column O.

This is my code below to process **331,000+ rows**. Is it the most effective or fast way to do it?

```
Sub Delete Resigned ()

Dim i as Integer

For i = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
   If Instr(1, Cells(i, 3), "Resigned") <> 0 Then
      Cells(i,3).EntireRow.Delete
   End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance to the community!

Comment: Probably faster to use AutoFilter then delete all visible rows.

Comment: Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53419866/478884

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Delete Hundreds of Thousands of Criteria Rows

- It will take forever if the criteria column is not sorted.
- It is assumed that the data is in table format i.e. in a contiguous range (no empty rows or columns) with one row of headers.
- This solution will insert a helper column with an ascending integer sequence. Then it will sort the range by the criteria column, filter it, delete the critical rows (they are now in a contiguous range) and finally sort by and delete the helper column.
- It took less than 30 seconds for 1M rows and 26 columns with about 350k matching rows on my machine. Your feedback on its efficiency is most welcome.

```vb
Sub DeleteResigned()
    
    Dim dt As Double: dt = Timer
    
    Const FirstCriteriaCellAddress As String = "O1"
    Const Criteria As String = "Resigned"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Reference the worksheet and remove any filters.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    
    ' Reference the range.
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(FirstCriteriaCellAddress)
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = fCell.CurrentRegion
    
    ' Calculate the column index.
    Dim cIndex As Long: cIndex = fCell.Column - rg.Column + 1
    
    With rg.Columns(cIndex)
        ' Check if any criteria.
        If Application.CountIf(.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1), Criteria) _
                = 0 Then
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            MsgBox "No criteria found", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Insert a helper column containing an ascending integer sequence.
        .Insert xlShiftToRight, xlFormatFromRightOrBelow
        With .Offset(, -1)
            .NumberFormat = 0
            .Value = ws.Evaluate("ROW(" & .Address & ")")
        End With
    End With
    
    ' Sort the range by the criteria column.
    rg.Sort rg.Columns(cIndex + 1), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
    
    ' Reference the data range (no headers).
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    ' Filter the data of the criteria column.
    rg.AutoFilter cIndex + 1, Criteria
    
    ' Reference the visible data rows of the filtered range and delete them.
    Dim vdrg As Range: Set vdrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    vdrg.Delete xlShiftUp
    
    ' Sort by and delete the helper column.
    rg.Sort rg.Columns(cIndex), xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
    rg.Columns(cIndex).Delete xlShiftToLeft
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    Debug.Print Timer - dt

    MsgBox "Rows deleted.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works wonders as usual. It took about 15 seconds to sort it out. Thanks VBasic2008!

Comment: Is there a way to compile two codes like above for a different word and a different column?