# Is there a way to reduce the time for the following code?

Tags: excel, vba

My excel file has around 4000 lines of data from which he goes over and only keeps the ones which actually have a value different from 0 in column H, so from the 4000 lines there are 400-1500 lines left. Currently when running my code it takes a lot of time 5-15 minutes to pass through each line in column H in order to verify where is data and where not so that the lines without data are deleted.

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim dataArr As Variant, emptyRows() As Long, emptyCount As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    dataArr = ws.Range("A3:A" & lastRow).Value
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ReDim emptyRows(1 To UBound(dataArr, 1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(dataArr, 1)
        If IsEmpty(dataArr(i, 1)) Then
            emptyCount = emptyCount + 1
            emptyRows(emptyCount) = i + 2 ' Adding 2 to get the actual row number
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Delete the empty rows from the worksheet
    If emptyCount > 0 Then
        For i = emptyCount To 1 Step -1 ' Loop through the rows to delete
            ws.Rows(emptyRows(i)).Delete
        Next i
        
        MsgBox "Empty rows deleted.", vbInformation
    Else
        MsgBox "No empty rows found.", vbInformation
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Also I think there might be a better way to go around the empty row deletion but the previous mentioned code is what I'm currently using, since if I leave the data without deleting the empty lines I create gaps in the data that I'm copying over from a different sheet.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to deal with deleting a set of rows. 1) Union the to-delete-ranges together and delete at once. However, this can take a long time again if the amount is relatively big. 2) Use one column to insert a tag like "ZZZZZDELETE", sort your sheet in that column alphabetically and delete in one go (deleting chunks goes way quicker) with finding the first one and delete from there to the last one. An additional helper-column might be required up front if you need it sorted back to what it was before.

Comment: This code runs very quickly for me already, under 1 second. Curious which part is taking a long time for you - looping through the array, or deleting the sheet rows?

Comment: @Dominique OP already has code that deletes starting from the end. `For i = emptyCount To 1 Step -1`

Comment: I suggest where you are testing column H for non-zero, to  use the `Range.AutoFilter` or `Range.AdvancedFilter` method. Then copy the visible cells only to a different location; delete your entire data table and paste that result back to the original location. (Steps could be slightly different with the `AdvancedFilter`).

Comment: Deleting the rows takes around 14 minutes

Comment: Is the workbook on a shared drive eg onedrive .

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your worksheet including the top left and bottom right of the data (hide the middle). with the row (1,2,3) and column (A,B,C) headings and the name of the worksheet visible. Here is a [very efficient solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71967085) where you would just have to adjust the criteria and how the range is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a helper column and `Evaluate`:

```vb
Sub DeleteZerosInH()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long, addr As String, f As String, t, rngDel As Range, num
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    addr = "H3:H" & ws.Cells(rows.count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    
    t = Timer
    With ws.Range(addr).Offset(0, 10) 'use an empty column
        f = "=IF(" & addr & "<>0,""x"","""")"
        Debug.Print f
        .Value = ws.Evaluate(f)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngDel = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
            num = rngDel.count
            rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
        .ClearContents
    End With
    MsgBox "Deleted " & num & " rows in " & Round(Timer - t, 2) & " seconds"
    
    
End Sub
```

Approx. 11 sec to delete about 2,000 rows from 10,000

Comment: This bit works nicely considering the previous time was of 14 minutes, now it takes around 30~35 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Try for the delete part:
' Delete the empty rows from the worksheet
Dim ra As Range
If emptyCount > 0 Then
Set ra = ws.Cells(emptyRows(1), 1)

```
    For i = 2 To emptyCount
      Set ra = Union(ra, ws.Cells(emptyRows(i), 1))
    Next i
    ra.EntireRow.Delete
    MsgBox "Empty rows deleted.", vbInformation
Else
    MsgBox "No empty rows found.", vbInformation
End If
```