# Reversing an array of objects in a sheet

Tags: vba, vbscript, jscript, qlikview

I am writing a macro in vbscript to export objects from sheets in Qlikview to a ppt. In a sheet, I have some objects in a sheet, but when I extract then to ppt, they are coming in reverse order of their id. Suppose the object ids a sheet are CH1, CH2, CH3.. In the code when I read them, they start from backward like CH3, CH2, CH1.. I have to place each object in specific position in ppt, so need to read them in correct order. I am using following code :

```
set s=ActiveDocument.ActiveSheet
charts=s.GetSheetObjects

Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(pptiterno)
for i=lbound(charts) to ubound(charts)
    msgbox charts(i).getobjectid
```

If in the sheet the objects are from CH57 - CH67, in the code they come as CH67-CH57. But I want them from CH57 - CH67. I simply tried to reverse the loop like :

```
for i=ubound(charts) to lbound(charts)
```

but this does not work. Can someone help me to reverse this object array.

Thanks for any help

Comment: if you want to go backward you need to add `step -1` to your `for` line, the second one.  vba asumes `step 1`

Comment: @ScottCraner.. thanks for replying. As I am really new to vbscript, can you please show how to write this. Thanks for help

Comment: `for i=ubound(charts) to lbound(charts) Step -1`  This will step backward through the array.

Comment: @ScottCraner.. thanks. I'll try it now. May be you can change it to answer by the time I try it, so that I can accept it if it works for me :)

Comment: Thanks and it worked like charm....If u post it as answer, I will accept :)

Answer (score 0):

As was stated in the comments, vba defaults to a positive step of 1 in a `For` loop.  To step backwards one must tell vba to step backwards.

```
for i=ubound(charts) to lbound(charts) Step -1
```

positive integers are forward(1,2,3) and negative is backwards(10,9,8). The steps can be multiples; so `Step 2` is (1,3,5).

This does not work for a `For Each` loop.

A good work around for the `For Each` loop can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203329/reversing-the-items-in-a-collection)